# Unable to set the value in bean via h:inputtext

Tags: jsf

I have created a JSF page and a bean with the view scope. I am not able to set the value in bean via `<h:textarea>`. Below in my code (Bean and XHTML)

Bean class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
//@SessionScoped
public class ItemDetailsBean {
    private CmsItemEJBDTO item;
    private CmsItemEJBDTO detailItem;
    private CmsCartEJB cart;
    private int quantity;
    private int itemId;
    private  boolean question = false;

    private String userItemQuery;

    public ItemDetailsBean() {
        itemId = 0;
        quantity = 1;
    }
    @EJB
    private ShopManagerRemote shopManager;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean login;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{shoppingCart}")
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        if(login.getProfile()!=null){

            question=true;
        }else{  
            question=false;
        }   
    }

    public String getUserItemQuery() {
        System.out.println("getUserItemQuery  => "+userItemQuery);
        return userItemQuery;
    }

    public void setUserItemQuery(String userItemQuery) {
        System.out.println("setUserItemQuery(String userItemQuery)  => "+userItemQuery);
        this.userItemQuery = userItemQuery;
    }

    public void submitItemQuestion(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Queston:::::::  " + userItemQuery);
            if(userItemQuery!=null){

            shopManager.saveItemQuestion(shoppingCart.getShop().getShopId(), itemId, login.getProfile(), userItemQuery);
            }else{

                System.out.println("UserItemQuery is null............");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception while submitting item question");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }       
    }
    public boolean isQuestion() {
        System.out.println("question in isQuestion()  = "+ question);
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(boolean question) {

        System.out.println("question in setQuestion(boolean question)  = "+ question);
        this.question = question;
    }







}
```

XHTML code:

```
<div class="category-tab shop-details-tab"><!--category-tab-->
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Ask Question</a></li>

                            </ul>
                                    <h:commandButton action="#{itemDetailsBean.askItemQuestionListner}" value="Ask Question" id="dialogbtn" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-detault" style="float:right;" >
                                      <f:param name="itemId" value="#{itemDetailsBean.itemId}"></f:param>
                                      <f:param name="question" value="true"></f:param>
                                      <f:ajax execute="@this" update= "question" />
                                    </h:commandButton>
                        </div>

                                <h:panelGroup>
                                <p:panel rendered="#{itemDetailsBean.question}">
                                <div class="col-sm-7" id="question">

                                 <h1>Enter Your Questions Here!!!</h1>
                                 <h:inputTextarea value="#{itemDetailsBean.userItemQuery}" />

                                  <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-detault" value="Submit Answer"  >
                                     <f:param name="itemId" value="#{itemDetailsBean.itemId}"></f:param>
                                     <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" listener="#{itemDetailsBean.submitItemQuestion()}" ></f:ajax>
                                  </h:commandButton>



                                </div>
                            </p:panel>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                    </div>
```

The `textarea` tag is always calling `getUserItemQuery()` method. Please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the inputTextArea and commandButton inside a form.

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{itemDetailsBean.userItemQuery}" />

    <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-detault" value="Submit Answer"  >
                                 <f:param name="itemId" value="#{itemDetailsBean.itemId}"></f:param>
                                 <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{itemDetailsBean.submitItemQuestion()}" ></f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: `<f:ajax execute="@this"` should be `<f:ajax execute="@form"`

Comment: Dear sir, it is already in form tag, I am using form at the start of the body and at just before body tag.

Comment: @user3180510: Post things like that. Always create a [mcve]